# MS Word ShapeNode coordinates cannot obtain

Tags: c++, ms-word

I'm receiving an empty variant with hresult 0x800a01a8, when trying to get node coordinates of a shape in Ms word.

```
variant_t var;
HRESULT he = pShapeNode->get_Points(&var);
```

I receive an exception either from a text box or from just a shape line.
Basically, I need to draw a rectangle and also to check if there is one already with an appropriate configuration.

Comment: FWIW I'm getting an error `Object required` when I try the VBA Help sample code in VBA. This is Word 2010. It's possible there's a problem with the object in the object model... (i.e. it no longer works).

Comment: Does it tell you the error code?

Comment: Run-time error 424

Comment: It's 01A8 in hex, you are getting the same error. Word is broken (

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub VBA documentation since I know of no place to post true bugs... https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/issues/118

Comment: That's very nice of you.