# Points property of ShapeNode fails in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

The Code below implements the example presented in the [Microsoft ShapeNode.Points property (Word) article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shapenode.points):

```
Sub Test()
Dim PointsArray
Dim myDocument As Document
Dim currXvalue As Single
Dim currYvalue As Single

    Set myDocument = ActiveDocument
    With myDocument.Shapes(3).Nodes
        PointsArray = .Item(2).Points
        currXvalue = PointsArray(1, 1)
        currYvalue = PointsArray(1, 2)
        .SetPosition 2, currXvalue + 200, currYvalue + 300
    End With
End Sub
```

Execution of the line 3 generates the RTE 13 (Type Mismatch).  According to the Watch panel,

- the type of the Points property is the array of Single (which is
  correct)
- the type of the `myDocument.Shapes(3).Nodes.Item(2).Points`
  expression is Integer

See the screenshot below:
[image]

Verified on MS Word 2007.  [A problem of this kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197069/ms-word-shapenode-coordinates-cannot-obtain) exists for Word 2010.  However, it was verified that the problem does not exist for MS PowerPoint 2007 and MS Excel 2007.

Seems to be an error in the Word object model.  Can you please suggest a workaround?

Comment: According to the Link, it says the Shape should be **FreeForm Drawing**, is that true in your case ? I tried it, and the code works on a freeform drawing. But not on any other shape.

Comment: @Mikku, sure, it is a FreeForm.  Otherwise the Code would not be working in PowerPoint and Excel, as you (and I) noticed already.

Comment: @Mikku, could you please provide the conditions under which the Code worked for you?  I mean primarily the MS Word version and language

Comment: I am using Office 365

Comment: Impressing!  This means that the problem is fixed in online MS Word version.  I wonder whether it is fixed on modern desktop versions like 2016 and 2019

Comment: No I am using Desktop version only. But it is Office 365, doesn't say if it is 2016 or 19. Should be the latest one